# Whatsapp phone verification

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I updated my whatsapp recently and it stopped receiving messages. I uninstalled it and reinstall from play store. The issue now is that during phone verification it keeps saying unable to connect. My internet is on. I've even restarted my phone severally. I use Tecno w5 lite. Help

Comment: Maybe try a factory reset on your phone?
And your phone runs android?

Comment: "Play store"? Is this a Windows Phone?

Comment: Have you given the app the right permissions in order to make the connection?